# как из списка "достать" только числа

Tags: python

```
my_list = [1,'два',3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'ноль']

for num in my_list:
    if num == int:
        print(num)
    else:
        print('нет там никаких цифр')
```

**возвращает:**

```
нет там никаких цифр
нет там никаких цифр
нет там никаких цифр
нет там никаких цифр
нет там никаких цифр
нет там никаких цифр
нет там никаких цифр
нет там никаких цифр
нет там никаких цифр
нет там никаких цифр
```

Comment: `print([x for x in my_list if isinstance(x, (int, float))])`

Comment: спасибо, а как эта строчка будет выглядеть в развёрнутом виде?

Comment: my_list=[1,2,'fgh',4]
for x in my_list:
  if isinstance(x,(int,float)):
    print(x)

Answer (score 1):

Делайте проверку на тип так:

```
if type(num) is int:
```

Answer (score 1):

Для ваших задач отлично подойдёт стандартная функция `filter`:

```py
>>> my_list = [1,'два',3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'ноль']
>>> list(filter(lambda x: type(x) is int, my_list))
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> result = list(filter(lambda x: type(x) is int, my_list))
>>> print(result if result else "нет там никаких цифр")
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Чтобы вывести числа так, как задумываете вы, можно использовать такой код:

```py
my_list = [1,'два',3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'ноль']
result = filter(lambda x: type(x) is int, my_list)

if result:
    print(*result, sep="\n")
else:
    print("нет там никаких цифр")
```

Результат:

```
1
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: для проверки типов более идиоматично использовать специальную функцию `isinstance()` - `list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), my_list))` ;)

Comment: @MaxU спасибо, учту. А есть ли случаи, когда функция работает **корректнее**, чем прямое сравнение типов?

Comment: Пример: `isinstance(inherited_obj, BaseClass)` - вернет `True`, если объект `inherited_obj` принадлежит классу, унаследованному от `BaseClass`, а `type(inherited_obj) is BaseClass` -> `False`